# Crop a photo into a circle?

Tags: gratis, image-editor

I need to recommend a free software with which I can crop photos into a circle. I found a few (eg [here](https://crop-circle.imageonline.co)) but they are all online.

Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of possibilities. [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/) is one and it's the most known free image editor.

Here are tutorials for it as to how to create a circle image from your image:

- [official](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/CircleImage/)
- [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWI06_nqIN0)
- my TLDR summary:

1. Make sure that the image has alpha/transparency channel, if it doesn't, add it.
2. Use Ellipse selection tool with <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select a circle
3. Reverse selection and cut out the non-circle area.
4. Use `Image` -> `Crop to content` menu option.

Comment: Hello, GIMP is terribly unintuitive, but the video on YouTube is ideal. Thank you very much.